# Double request with pycurl on ElasticSearch

Tags: python, mysql, elasticsearch

I decided to code a short python programme who used mysql and ElasticSearch.
When my rowcount return more one result, my seconde query of ElasticSearch doesn't work.
this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
c = pycurl.Curl()
b = StringIO.StringIO()


def BuildUrl():
    return "http://"+ip_ES+":"+port_ES+"/"+index_ES+"/"+type_ES+"/"
def CreateRqtES(brand, count):
    request = BuildUrl()+'_search?sort=title:asc&from=0&size='+str(count)+'&q=brand:'+brand
    print("link:", request)
    try:
        c.setopt(c.URL, request)
        c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
        c.perform()
        print "test" 
        try:
            decoded = json.loads(b.getvalue())
            json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
            for index in decoded['hits']['hits']:
                var =  index['_source']['link']
                print var
        except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
            print "JSON format error"
        except IOError as e:
            print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
    except Exception, e:
        logger.info("[-][Error] pycurl")

def connectionBDD():
    try:
        con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'mydbb')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM  newsletters")
            for i in range(cur.rowcount):
                row = cur.fetchone()
                print row[1], row[2]
                CreateRqtES(row[1], row[2])

    except _mysql.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```

At the seconde request of Es I've no result.
How to resolve that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I refined the error message, and now ive got this error for my seconde request:

> Extra data: line 1 column 5499 - line 1 column 10973 (char 5499 - 10973)

But when I put my second request at the first place, I've got no error ...